# How to show html tags from javascript variable to a div id?

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to show the testTag variable to the div after i click the button. When i clicked it only shows the label of the option tag and not the full select tags.
Please help! This is my code.

```js
function showDropdown() {
  
 var textTag = "<select>";
 var textOptions = ["option1","option2","option3"];
 
 for (i = 0; i < textOptions.length; i++) {
  textTag += '<options value="' + textOptions[i] + '">' + textOptions[i] + "</options>";
  
 }
 
 textTag += "</select>";
  
 document.getElementById("dropdownTest").innerHTML= textTag;
 console.log(textTag);
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Show dropdown</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" id="showDrop" value="Show dropdown" onClick="showDropdown()">
<div id="dropdownTest"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've voted to close this question because the issue is just a typo.

Answer (score 4):

It's called `<option>`, not `<options>`:

```js
function showDropdown() { 
    var textTag = "<select>";
    var textOptions = ["option1","option2","option3"];
 
    // declare "i"!
    for (var i = 0; i < textOptions.length; i++) {
        // change this line
        textTag += '<option value="' + textOptions[i] + '">' + textOptions[i] + "</option>";      
    }
 
    textTag += "</select>";
  
    document.getElementById("dropdownTest").innerHTML = textTag;
    console.log(textTag);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Show dropdown</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="showDrop" value="Show dropdown" onClick="showDropdown()">
    <div id="dropdownTest"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow. im pulling my hair off. Im just starting to learn javascript. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3080440 Actually, that was an HTML error, not a JavaScript error.